# guarantee the first process to work on a file can finish in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a queue of workers that want to process thousands of accounts. They will each use a model to make predictions. The model is a file on the hard drive that has to be prepared. When the first process detects the model file is not there, it should create it. I want to make sure that the first process to detect the model file does not exist can create it while other processes wait for it to finish preparing the model before starting.

I think using an `Agent` for a mutex is the way to go here, but I'm not sure how to start the agent and so that each process will sit and wait until the agent says its ok to proceed (the mutex is released). I also would like to know if `Agent` is not the right solution…

I'm ok with generating the model for each node/instance so a distributed lock is not necessary here.

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just run the preparation synchronously _before_ spawning all the processes to process it? The rule of thumb is, if you feel you need a mutex in OTP, you are most likely mistaken.

Comment: They spawn in response to account information changing, so unless I do it on deploy/instance start up, there is no guaranteed time that it would run before any other process that needs it will start. Also, the file needs to be regenerated regularly, so when an old one is made invalid, there is definitely no clean place to prepare a new one before all other processes that use it will start

Comment: I do not get. You have a supervisor, that creates a file and then spawns all workers. All you need to revalidate the file when it expires is _just to kill this supervisor_.

Comment: so, I'm using exq because these jobs need to be executed even if the instances restart, they also need to be throttled and queued because they all get queued within an hour or so (by a php app that triggers them to start via redis per account) and it would overwhelm the instances if they all ran at once in pure erlang processes. I appreciate your answer because it shines light on how to solve problems like this in elixir, but mine seems like a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comments above, the best scenario, in my opinion, would be:

— one creates the `Supervisor` that basically creates the file and then spawns all the workers:

```
file = FileProducer.create()
children = Enum.map(1..20, 
  &worker(FileHandler, [file], id: :"FileHandler_#{&1}")
)
supervise(children)
```

— this supervisor is to be supervised by the `Application` (included into the supervision tree.)

— as soon as the file is expired, *just kill this supervisor*. The application will resurrect it, and the whole startup loop will be passed through.